# how to pass a hidden parameter using jquery.get

Tags: jquery, forms, get

I want to post a form using jquery.get

I went through the docs at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

I cant find any way of passing a hidden parameter when making the GET request.

How do I send the hidden parameter via Jquery GET request?

Comment: What would you consider a hidden parameter?

Comment: sounds like you need to post.

Comment: Define "hidden". Variables sent both over `GET` and `POST` are *not* hidden. `POST` variables are obfuscated since they are not shown in the query string, but a simple look at the headers will show them to you.

Answer (score 0):

On a `GET` the parameters are exposed and readable. There is no hidden concept.
If you want to hide and not expose values to the naked eye, you would need to `POST`.

Comment: POST isn't really hidden either. Just look at the headers.

Comment: Note however that it isn't truly hidden (you can't completely hide anything client-side)

Comment: Well I am talking in terms of the url, i.e. naked eye

Answer (score 0):

GET is not Hidden use post instead (although its not "hidden") further you can use both parameters in GET and POST e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php?GET_PARAM=GET_VALUE",
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
})
```

this is not good practice because you have to use $_GET and $_POST both in PHP on server side which might get you in trouble or you end up in "spaghetti code"

Comment: you can still use $_REQUEST[] but its not really better

Comment: yes but that is not a good way because it by default contains $_COOKIE which may cause problem..